# How to get rid of Lerna Warnings on "yarn" command

Tags: yarnpkg, lerna

I am running "yarn" and I am getting all of these lerna warnings. Is there a way I can hide these so they do not appear everytime I install my packages?

[image]

Comment: Which versions of `lerna` / `node` / `yarn` are you using? Because I am not seeing any on the following setup: `3.22.1` / `v12.19.0` / `1.22.10`